# How do you pronounce RND (Research and Development)?

Tags: pronunciation, acronyms

Apparently, RND is an acronym for Research and Development. I'm used to R&D.

How do you pronounce RND? Would it be "are and dee", like the form I'm used to? Or would it be "are en dee", like it's spelled?

Some sources declaring RND as an acronym for Research and Development:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RND
- https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/RND
- https://www.abbreviations.com/RND
- https://www.acronymfinder.com/RND.html
- https://www.abbreviationfinder.org/acronyms/rnd.html

Comment: If anyone has used RND that way, it's a misspelling. Possibly a typo. I'd say "ar and dee" just the way you say you would.

Comment: Do you have an example of RND? "R'n'B music" and similar forms are common, but not "R'n'D" or anything similar at least in UK or US. Wikipedia lists R&D and R+D. Just pronounce "R and D" , with "and" reduced according to your dialect.

Comment: [Acronym Finder](https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/RND) asserts that RND is a valid initialism: << RND Research and Development >> The two d sounds are always conflated even when 'and' or '&' is opted for, as in _R 'n D_ (which is, I'd say, indistinguishable from RND).

Comment: "RND" is pronounced the same as "R&D". Since they're both abbreviations, it doesn't matter how they're spelled. Follow local conventions.

Comment: @StuartF I added some references.

Comment: RND may be valid but most people use R&D.

Answer (score 2):

There was one TV Episode where Homer J Simpson wants to know what J stands for. He eventually gets to know that J was Jay.

I think he says something like this : "I will no longer be called Homer J Simpson ; I will be called Homer Jay Simpson" the "joke" being that both are indistinguishable.

Here is one Company with that name : [RND](https://www.linkedin.com/company/rnd---research-and-development) in Norway

[image: RND]

It is listed @ [the Free Dictionary](https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/RND) & [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RND) & various other web-sites. The Wiki also says it is useful where "&" is not allowed.

Whether you read it "ARR-EN-DEE" or "ARR-AND-DEE" or "ARR-END-DEE", it all sounds like "ARR-END-EE", being indistinguishable, hence it is immaterial.

Comment: "useful where "&" is not allowed" - that seems to be the key.  +1.  (For my taste, everything else could be omitted.)